# ios SystemSound will not respond to volume buttons

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Ive used SystemSound in my app in order to play simple sound effects. In addition to this I play a musicvideo through the MPMoviePlayerController - now when I turn the volume up/down the music from the video responds as intended (lowering the volume up/down).

But the system sounds that are played does not respond to the volume. Im playing the system sounds when the user taps certain areas in the app. Heres a snippet of my code for that:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
   SystemSoundID completeSound = nil;

   //yellow folder in xcode doesnt need subdirectory param
   //blue folder (true folder) will need to use subdirectory:@"dirname"
   NSURL *sound_path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: target_sound_filename withExtension: @"wav"];

   AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)sound_path, &completeSound);
   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(completeSound);
}
```

PS. I doublechecked that my "Settings->Sounds->Ringer and Alerts->Change With Buttons" is set to ON (as I read on some other SO answers that leaving this option OFF will cause systemsound to not respond to the volume buttons)

Further the reason for using systemsound is that it gave the most accurate and responsive results when playing multiple sounds (like in a game).

Id prefer to not use OpenAL if possible (even through 3rd party sound libraries like [Finch](https://github.com/zoul/Finch) or [CocosDenshion](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/cocosdenshion%3afaq))

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) class for playing sounds that are controlled by the user's volume settings (non-system sounds).

You can retain instances of `AVAudioPlayer` for each sound file that you use regularly and simply call the `play` method. Use `prepareToPlay` to preload the buffers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I did some tests earlier on AVAudioPlayer and it had some lag issues.. Guess my only option then is to use an OpenAL library? Its not possible to get SystemSound to respond to the volume buttons?

Comment: @am_, did you preload the files, retain instances of AVAudioPlayer as I mention in my (updated) answer, and use `prepareToPlay`? It works instantly for me. I even use it for UI sounds. SystemSound is for "alerts". OpenAL is just going to use Core Audio (AVAudioPlayer) anyway.

Comment: Hm, I guess I could use prepareToPlay to load all my wav files as soon as the app starts (i have around 60 wav files). On the finch homepage it is mentioned that AVAudioPlayer has lag in its play method.. But Ill try it out tomorrow and see how it works! Will let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Cheers to Marcus for suggesting that i could retain instances of AVAudioPlayer for each sound file and use prepareToPlay to preload the sounds. It might be to help for others looking for the same solution so here is how I did it (feel free to comment if anyone have suggestions for improvements)

```
//top of viewcontroller.m
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *audioPlayers;
@synthesize audioPlayers = _audioPlayers;

//on viewDidLoad
self.audioPlayers = [NSMutableDictionary new];

//creating the instances and adding them to the nsmutabledictonary in order to retain them
//soundFile is just a NSString containing the name of the wav file
NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:s ofType:@"wav"];
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile] error:nil];
//audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

//add to dictonary with filename (omit extension) as key
[self.audioPlayers setObject:audioPlayer forKey:s];

//then i use the following to play the sound later on (i have it on a tap event)
//get pointer reference to the correct AVAudioPlayer instance for this sound, and play it
AVAudioPlayer *foo = [self.audioPlayers objectForKey:target_sound_filename];
[foo play];

//also im not sure how ARC will treat the strong property, im setting it to nil in dealloc atm.
-(void)dealloc {
    self.audioPlayers = nil;
}
```